# Trying to delete Realm object in Swift UIKit app and getting an error "Object has been deleted or invalidated."

Tags: swift, uikit, realm

I'm sorry if it seems like a duplicate, but I've read other topics about that and haven't found a solution.

*What I'm trying to achieve*:
Save a photo to Realm and use the Results<PhotoModel.self> array to display those photos in a TableView.

*The whole app idea*:
Client for Unsplash API that shows photos in collectionView - MainVC - where you can open any photo in a separate ViewController - DetailedVC - and then you can mark it as Favorite and it could be found using tabBar in another ViewController - FavoriteVC in a TableView.

*Problem*:
When I'm on DetailVC pressing a button to save - it works. When I then press it to delete - it works. When I then press the button to save it again, or go to MainVC(which is a collectionView) and try to open the same photo it's crashing.

In my view, I'm not trying to achieve this Realm object after deleting it when pressing a button to save it again or opening it in DetailedVC from MainVC, because I'm working with "local" data which came to me from JSON and was saved to a "local" variable. Not in RealmDB objects.

Method that I use to save/delete.

```
@objc func addToFavorite() {
        guard let photoObject = photoObject else { return }
        if realm.objects(PhotoModel.self).contains(where: { $0.id == photoObject.id }) {
            deleteFromDB(photoObject)
        } else {
            saveToDB(photoObject)
        }
    }
```

DetailedVC https://pastecode.io/s/gegu7tkr

Comment: Hi, I'm having a same issue. Did you find out the solution?

Comment: Yes, I did. I found this article - https://santoshm.com.np/2020/10/10/rlmexception-reason-object-has-been-deleted-or-invalidated-ios-realm/
It helped.

Comment: The whole problem is that since I've implemented Realm I've started to use classes instead of structs. And when you deleting class it obviously deletes it from memory... So you are unable to use it ever since. You just should create another object from what you've parsed when you are saving it to Realm.